# How to put condition for string not to follow each other

Tags: python, string

I have a exclusion_list =  ['and', 'or', 'not']

My string is `'Nick is not or playing football and or not cricket'`

- In the string if exclusion_list is coming `together` then it should take first one

My expected out is `'Nick is not  playing football and cricket'`

Code is below

```
search_value = 'Nick is not or playing football and or not cricket'
exclusion_list =  ['and', 'or', 'not']
search_value_2 = search_value.split(' ')
for i in range(len(search_value_2)):
    if search_value_2[i] in exclusion_list and search_value_2[i+1] in exclusion_list:
        search_value_2.replace(search_value_2[i+1], '')
' '.join(search_value_2)
```

As from suggestion i have modified the code

```
search_value = 'Nick is not or playing football and or not cricket'
exclusion_list =  ['and', 'or', 'not']
search_value_2 = search_value.split(' ')
for i in range(0,len(search_value_2)-2):
    if search_value_2[i] in exclusion_list and search_value_2[i+1] in exclusion_list:
        search_value_2.remove(search_value_2[i+1])
' '.join(search_value_2)
```

My out>> 'Nick is not playing football and not cricket'

Expected out> 'Nick is not playing football and cricket'

Comment: replace doesn't replace the string in place, it returns a new one

Comment: @sayse so what to modified inthe code

Comment: `i` is an integer so `i in exclusion_list` will be always `False` hence the conditional is useless

Comment: @cards i have edited, still same error

Comment: I don't think the duplicate tackles the main problem of the code.

Comment: also the condition on the right of `and` is wrong (same problem)

Comment: and the `replace`...

Comment: @cards I have modified that also, i got index out of range

Comment: and the last index (due to `i+1`) ...

Comment: @Matthias correct i need to consider only `i` not `i+1`, i+1 has to delete if its coming together

Comment: I think the best a more straightforward way is to use a regular expression

Comment: @cards not having good knowledge on regex

Comment: it could be the right momemnt then:)

Comment: Based on the original code I have an answer ready, but since the question is still closed I can't show it.

Comment: @Matthias do i need to ask again? or you can edit the question itself

Comment: We already have two reopen votes, but if no others come in the question will still be closed. If you ask a new question I'll answer that.

Comment: @Matthias i have almost reached the answer, can you check edited one

Comment: You made parts of it worse. Never delete something from a list while you're iterating over it. Since this is not a discussion forum I will stop commenting here now. Either wait until this question is reopened (might never happen) or ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040098/how-to-remove-from-same-type-of-string-coming-together-using-python

Comment: @Matthias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040098/how-to-remove-from-same-type-of-string-coming-together-using-python